# how to write javascript code within php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have got a form, on clicking the submit button:

```
<form>
   <h2 style="text-align: center">* * * PROJECTS * * *</h2>
<br>
   <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="document.write('<?php GetCellValues() ?>');" Value="SAVE">
<br>
</form>

<?php
    function GetCellValues()
    {
        echo("Save");
        var str = '';
        var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var table=document.getElementById("project");
        for (var i=0;i<table.rows[0].cells.length;i++)
        {
            str = str + (table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML) + ', ' ;     
        }
        for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
        {
            str += '\n' + "0" + c + ', ';
            var row = rows[c];
            var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
            for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)
            {
                str += inputs[k].value + ', ';
            }
        }
    }
?>

<?php
$handle = fopen("data.csv", "w");
$hide = $_REQUEST['hide'];
fwrite($handle,$hide);

$file = file('data.csv');
$lines = count($file);

echo'<table id = "projest" border = "1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style = "width: 60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-color: brown; background-color:gray;">';
echo'<tr cellpadding="100">
    <th width="15%"><h3>Sl.No.</h3></th>
    <th width="15%"><h3>Project Name</h3></th>
    <th width="15%"><h3>ChangeDate</h3></th>
    <th width="15%"><h3>Changed By</h3></th>
</tr>';
for ($i=1; $i<$lines; $i++) 
{

  $part = explode(',', $file[$i]);

  echo'<tr>
    <td align= "center" width="5%">'.$part[0].'</td>
    <td align= "center" width="25%"><input type="text" value='.$part[1].'></td>
    <td align= "center" width="25%"><input type="text" value='.$part[2].'></td>
    <td align= "center" width="25%"><input type="text" value='.$part[3].'></td> 
  </tr>';
}
echo'</table>'; 
?>
```

But not able to submit the form, if I call the javascript code on onClick, it works.what is the problem in this code, Is there any work around for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Comment: PHP runs on the serverside where there is no javascript engine, the javascript has to be echo'ed to the browser just like HTML, as that is where javascript is executed. As a sidenote, this is generally a bad idea, you should have your javascript in it's own file instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to echo the whole JScript function because PHP doesn't know what you're doing:

```
echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>function GetCellValues()
    {
        //echo('Save'); use document.write()?
        var str = '';
        var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var table=document.getElementById("project");
        for (var i=0;i<table.rows[0].cells.length;i++)
        {
            str = str + (table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML) + ', ' ;     
        }
        for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
        {
            str += '\n' + "0" + c + ', ';
            var row = rows[c];
            var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
            for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)
            {
                str += inputs[k].value + ', ';
            }
        }
    }</script>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   echo "<script> your javascript code   </script>";


?>


php will work from server javascript will work from client side
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix javascript code (which is executed on client side) and php (which is server oriented).

First, your function `GetCellValues` is javascript, not php, so replace your firsts `<?php` and `?>` by `<script>` and `</script>`.

Then, you need a form and a button type=submit, or an ajax call.